# Linear Algebra Done Right(2nd edition): how do we get equation 5.22?

Tags: linear-algebra

In Linear Algebra Done Right(2nd Edition), in the proof of proposition 5.21, in proving that (b) implies (d), it says "Thus every vector in V is a linear combination of eigenvectors of T. Hence

5.22      $V=null(T-\lambda_1I)+...+null(T-\lambda_mI)$
"

I'm wondering why the fact that "every vector in V is a linear combination of eigenvectors of T" implies $V=null(T-\lambda_1I)+...+null(T-\lambda_mI)$.

From my understanding, this equation says that every element  $v\in V$ could be written as sum of elements in the null spaces. But all I could get is for any element $v\in V$ it holds that $v=a_1 v_1+...+a_m v_m$, where $a_1,...,a_m$ are constant (not necessarily eigenvalues), $v_1,...,v_m$ are eigenvectors. Is it because $a_iv_i$ satisfy $(T-\lambda_iI)a_iv_i=0$ by the fact that $v_i$ is eigenvector with eigenvalue $\lambda_i$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By assumption, $T$ has $m$ distinct eigenvalues, say,
$$
\lambda_1, \lambda_2, \ldots, \lambda_m
$$
with the corresponding eigenvectors
$$
\mathbf{v}_1, \mathbf{v}_2, \ldots, \mathbf{v}_m
$$
which constitute a basis $\mathcal{B}$ for $V$.

By definition,
$$
T \mathbf{v}_i = \lambda_i \mathbf{v}_i \ \ \mbox{for} \ \ i = 1, 2, \ldots, m
$$
or equivalently
$$
(T - \lambda_i I) \mathbf{v}_i = 0  \ \ \mbox{for} \ \ i = 1, 2, \ldots, m
$$

This shows clearly that
$$
\{ \mathbf{v}_i \}
$$
forms a basis for the one-dimensional null-space for the eigenvalue $\lambda_i$, which is denoted as $\mbox{null}(T - \lambda_i)$.

Since we can express every vector $\mathbf{x} \in V$ uniquely as
$$
\mathbf{x} = c_1 \mathbf{v}_1 + c_2 \mathbf{v}_2 + \ldots + c_m \mathbf{v}_m
$$
(as $\mathcal{B} = \{  \mathbf{v}_1, \ldots,  \mathbf{v}_m \}$ is a basis for $V$),
it follows that
$$
V = \mbox{null}(T - \lambda_1 I) \oplus  \mbox{null}(T - \lambda_2 I) \oplus
\cdots  \oplus  \mbox{null}(T - \lambda_m I).
$$

Comment: Thank you very much! This is very helpful!

Comment: Also, in your proof, using the fact that $\mathbf{v}_1,...,\mathbf{v}_m$ is a basis of $V$, we already get $\mathbf{x}$ could be uniquely expressed ass sum of elements from the nullspaces, implying the sum is a direct sum. Does this mean that what the book does is redundant? The book shows "$0=u_1+...+u_m$" implies $u_j$ are all zero.